# Tkinter button changes color after having hovered on it

Tags: python, tkinter

I create a button that I want to be white/red when disabled/active:

`self.btn = tk.Button(cfg.win, text="Button", name = "btn", state="disabled", bg="white", activebackground="red")`

where self refers to my Gui class, cfg.win is a Tkinter window with the .Tk() method.

Then a callback changes the color of the button:

```
self.btn.configure(state = "active")
```

The button turns red. When I hover on the mouse with the mouse the color is still red. However, when I leave the area of the button it turns white. The button stays active. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see that a button state can be normal, active or disabled. 
The documentation does not say much 
[tkinter buttons](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm) but it appears that the button is active when I hover on it with the mouse, and normal when my mouse is not on its area. 
So the following did the trick

```
self.btn.configure(state = "normal", relief="raised", bg = "red")
```